# Is there an equivalent to Kafka's KTable in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

[Apache Kafka has a concept of a KTable](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#ktable), where

> where each data record represents an update

Essentially, I can consume a kafka topic, and only keep the latest message for per key.

Is there a similar concept available in Apache Flink?   I have read about [Flink's Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/streaming.html#defining-a-table-on-a-stream), but does not seem to be solving the same problem.

Some help comparing and contrasting the 2 frameworks would be helpful.  I am not looking for which is better or worse.  But rather just how they differ.  The answer for which is right would then depend on my requirements.

Comment: If you want to compare both, I would recommend to read the Flink/dataArtisans as well as the Confluent blog: https://flink.apache.org/blog/ | https://data-artisans.com/blog and https://www.confluent.io/blog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. Flink's Table API and its `Table` class do not correspond to Kafka's KTable. The Table API is a relational language-embedded API (think of SQL integrated in Java and Scala).

Flink's DataStream API does not have a built-in concept that corresponds to a KTable. Instead, Flink offers sophisticated state management and a KTable would be a regular operator with [keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#keyed-state).

For example, a stateful operator with two inputs that stores the latest value observed from the first input and joins it with values from the second input, can be implemented with a `CoFlatMapFunction` as follows:

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> first = ...
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> second = ...

DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> result = first
  // connect first and second stream
  .connect(second)
  // key both streams on the first (Long) attribute
  .keyBy(0, 0)
  // join them
  .flatMap(new TableLookup());

// ------

public static class TableLookup 
  extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Long,String>, Tuple2<Long,String>, Tuple2<String,String>> {

  // keyed state
  private ValueState<String> lastVal;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration conf) {
    ValueStateDescriptor<String> valueDesc = 
      new ValueStateDescriptor<String>("table", Types.STRING);
    lastVal = getRuntimeContext().getState(valueDesc);
  }

  @Override
  public void flatMap1(Tuple2<Long, String> value, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception {
    // update the value for the current Long key with the String value.
    lastVal.update(value.f1);
  }

  @Override
  public void flatMap2(Tuple2<Long, String> value, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception {
    // look up latest String for current Long key.
    String lookup = lastVal.value();
    // emit current String and looked-up String
    out.collect(Tuple2.of(value.f1, lookup));
  }
}
```

In general, state can be used very flexibly with Flink and let's you implement a wide range of use cases. There are also more state types, such as [`ListState` and `MapState`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state) and with a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html) you have fine-grained control over time, for example to remove the state of a key if it has not been updated for a certain amount of time (KTables have a configuration for that as far as I know).

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same. A `KTable` in Kafka Streams is a "hybrid" if you wish: the materialized state as well as downstream changelog stream. AFAIK, Flink does not have the notion of a changelog stream. Thus, I guess you can get the "state part" only with this approach. This is sufficient to implement KStream-KTable lookup join using CoFlatMap -- but it's only one use case for a KTable in Kafka Streams.

Comment: In fact, it is easy to emit a changelog stream from any stateful operator in Flink. It's just a matter of encoding the changes and all downstream operators need to know how to handle the input changelog stream. In Flink changelog streams are also not limited to key-upsert changelogs but can encode the changes as accumulation and retraction messages which is more flexible. Both types of changelogs are used by [Flink's SQL support](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/streaming.html#table-to-stream-conversion). AFAIK, KTables are limited to key-upsert changes.

Comment: Correct, KTable use key-upserts. And if corse you can emit a changelog stream: but none of the provided DSL operators will understand it (do they) -- thus, you need to implement your own operators. Overall, a very cumbersome approach to reimplement everything by yourself. -- Flink has other advantages. But KTable/Changlog support is not really there.

Comment: Changelog support is covered by Flink's relational APIs (Table API and SQL).

Comment: @FabianHueske I'm not sure to follow, when you say changelog support is covered ? Can you explain ? I don't see any KTable like capability in Flink at all. A Dynamic table, is a kstream in Kafka stream, yes you can convert your Dynamic Table in a change log Stream, But you will have to rebuild your KTable yourself. Not easy task at all

Comment: A KTable is a representation of a special dynamic table, i.e., a dynamic table that is upserted per key. Right now, there is no built-in support to create such a representation from a stream, but you can implement KTable semantics (and much more) yourself. Built-in support for this is on the way. In principle, Flink's relational APIs do not (artificially) differentiate between streams and tables but deals only with tables that change over time (append-only=KStream, key-upserts=KTables, arbitrary changes=...).